# MySQLdb query hanging

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python

I'm using the MySQLdb package in python to connect to a local database.

I connect to the database as follows:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=os.environ.get("DEVELOPMENT_SQL_SERVER"), user=os.environ.get("DEVELOPMENT_SQL_USER"), db=os.environ.get("SQL_WORDS_DB"))
```

where the host, user, and database are all loaded correctly from a `.env` file.

I then try to execute a command as such:

```
cur = db.cursor()
sql_command = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keywords(id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, case_num INT(6), correlation DECIMAL(5,2), word VARCHAR(20));"
cur.execute(sql_command)
```

When i run my program, it hangs on the cur.execute command with no indication that it will complete.

I found this error to be strange, since it has worked in the past without problems. But now when i try to run this code it has this error.

Comment: did you check the grants?

Comment: I don't think the grants shouldn't be an issue here because I'm using the root user on my local machine